# Finding slope of a curve at a point

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find the slope of the curve $$y=\frac{1}{x-4}$$ at $x=8.$

My try:

$$m=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$$

$$= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{(8+h)-4}-\frac{1}{(8)-4}}{h}$$

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{h-4}-\frac{1}{4}}{h}$$

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\frac{4-h+4}{4(h-4)}}{h}$$

This doesn't seem correct, and I'm unsure of how to proceed. What are the steps to solving this? I would like to do this using the limit definition of the derivative instead of just taking the derivative. Thanks.

Comment: Notice that $(8+h)-4=h+4$ in the second line of your try. Correct it and do some algebra you will arrive a cancellation. The result of your limit is $\frac{-1}{16}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correcting the second line as suggested, the third line becomes

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{h + 4} - \frac{1}{4}}{h}$$

Which then becomes

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{4 - (h +4)}{4 \cdot (h+4)}}{h}$$

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{- h}{4 \cdot (h+4)}}{h}$$

The h's will then cancel:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{- h}{4 \cdot (h+4) \cdot h}$$

Leaving you with

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{- 1}{4 \cdot (h+4)}$$

Now you can proceed to find the limit of the function as $h \to 0$

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{- 1}{4 \cdot (0+4)} = \frac{-1}{16}$$